# Is there a way to cite two articles which share some authors in a single sentence?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I want to cite a pair of articles using in-text citations and they share some of the authors between them.

Does there exist any acceptable way to do this by joining them in a single sentence?

---

A MWE would have the following articles:

[1] Tom, Dick, and Harry. (2021). Generic Article Name. Journal 1.

[2] Tom and Harry. (2022). Another Generic Article. Journal 2.

And if the authors did not overlap, I would write something like:

*"As the results of Tom, Dick, and Harry [1], which are corroborated by the study by Tom and Harry [2], show..."*

Ideally, I would like to shorten this to something more like:

*"As the results of Tom and Harry [2], as well as their prior work with Dick [1], show..."*

Is it acceptable to abbreviate citations like this or some other way? Or should I go with the longer version?

Comment: Since you're using numerical citations, do you really want/need to write the authors' names too?

Comment: Not really, but that's how I have been doing it. Do you suggest dropping either? I feel like they make the text clearer than if I just used the number, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: It depends on where you want to publish. This is a question of style. Generally such questions have as part of the answer "check the local style." Find out what they want in the place you hope to publish, whether a journal or an academic committee or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with either of your two examples, whether the names are overlapping or not. I say this with the caveat that every field and journal has its own particular style and conventions. My experience is primarily in linguistics, which seems to have a bit more intra-discipline variation and flexibility than some other fields.

If you think it sounds awkward, you could simply rewrite the sentence to avoid the names, e.g. something like:

*"As shown in prior work [1,2]"*

Comment: Thank you! I was unsure of how to write it, but it's reassuring that you don't find my examples too outlandish. I like your example too, since it's very concise, I may use it as well.